# property translate in angular

Tags: angularjs, translate, angular-translate

i want to translate a property to fetch the data from array
i have array like this:

```
<Country>
<Id>183</Id>
<Name_Ar>المملكة المتحدة</Name_Ar>
<Name_En>United Kingdom</Name_En>
</Country>
<Country>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name_Ar>أفغانستان</Name_Ar>
<Name_En>Afghanistan</Name_En>
</Country>
```

and i have select with ng-options or ng-repeat

```
 <select ng-model="employee.Nationality_Id"> <option ng-repeat="county in countries" value="{{county.Id}}">{{county.Name_En}}</option> </select>
```

i want to translate the property `{{county.Name_En}}` to `{{county.Name_Ar}}`
to get the value based on current language

Comment: Here you have an xml format. angular-translate will work with json

Comment: no problem, im working with json but is there any solution to my case ?

Comment: angular-translate will take care if you switch language. you just need to provide json object for each language and configure angular-translate to your project.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani im fetching the json array from api 
i just want angular to get value of a property instead of another based on current language

Comment: Ok, Assign json array to controller's scope variable and use that in your template.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani do you have any example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of fetching data like `{{county.Name_En}}` we can write this in different formula like `{{county["{{'Name' | tranlsate}}"]}}`

then we will add translate variable in translation arrays 
en:

```
Name: 'Name_En'
```

Ar:

```
Name: 'Name_Ar'
```

Comment: If I do {{county["{{'Name' | translate }}"]}} I get an error (Unterminated quote) because with the first closing }} angular thinks this is the end of the interpolation. Are you sure you can use a filter inside of an array key? The weird thing is that it works when I do it in a directive. Also you wrote translate wrong in your answer ;)